# Failed to install index ( Geodjango related)

Tags: django, geodjango

I am using `geoDjango`. I have installed following packages from source `Gdal`, `proj1.4`, `geos3.3.5` and `Postgis2.0.1`. I am ubuntu user. When I run `syncdb` after that I am getting following error. Am I missing something? thanks

```
Superuser created successfully.
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Failed to install index for cities.City model: operator class "gist_geometry_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"

Failed to install index for cities.District model: operator class "gist_geometry_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"

Failed to install index for cities.PostalCodeCA model: operator class "gist_geometry_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"

Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a postgis template and load the relevent postgis.sql

say your postgis path is /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib
run this

```
POSTGIS_SQL_PATH=/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib
sudo -u postgres createdb  -E UTF8 template_postgis1 # Create the template spatial database.
sudo -u postgres createlang  -d template_postgis1 plpgsql # Adding PLPGSQL language support.
sudo -u postgres psql  -d postgres -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate='true' WHERE datname='template_postgis1';"
sudo -u postgres psql  -d template_postgis1 -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/postgis.sql # Loading the PostGIS SQL routines
sudo -u postgres psql  -d template_postgis1 -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/spatial_ref_sys.sql
sudo -u postgres psql  -d template_postgis1 -c "GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;" # Enabling users to alter spatial tables.
sudo -u postgres psql   -d template_postgis1 -c "GRANT ALL ON spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;"
```

your database then  needs to then be created with the created templete template

```
sudo -u postgres createdb   database_name -T template_postgis1
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've changed the `POSTGIS_SQL_PATH' . But I am getting same. X-(

Comment: `Postgis2.0.1` is not supported by `django1.4`. I downgraded to `Postgis1.5` and runs your commands. and It worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't downgrade, but instead used the backward compatibility patch on template_postgis given in Jeasoft's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe I'm a little late but I fixed this problem (Django 1.4.x, Postgis 2.0.1 and PostgreSQL 9.2) creating an operator class in the template_postgis database like this:

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS gist_geometry_ops
FOR TYPE geometry USING GIST AS
STORAGE box2df,
OPERATOR        1        <<  ,
OPERATOR        2        &<  ,
OPERATOR        3        &&  ,
OPERATOR        4        &>  ,
OPERATOR        5        >>  ,
OPERATOR        6        ~=  ,
OPERATOR        7        ~   ,
OPERATOR        8        @   ,
OPERATOR        9        &<| ,
OPERATOR        10       <<| ,
OPERATOR        11       |>> ,
OPERATOR        12       |&> ,

OPERATOR        13       <-> FOR ORDER BY pg_catalog.float_ops,
OPERATOR        14       <#> FOR ORDER BY pg_catalog.float_ops,
FUNCTION        8        geometry_gist_distance_2d (internal, geometry, int4),

FUNCTION        1        geometry_gist_consistent_2d (internal, geometry, int4),
FUNCTION        2        geometry_gist_union_2d (bytea, internal),
FUNCTION        3        geometry_gist_compress_2d (internal),
FUNCTION        4        geometry_gist_decompress_2d (internal),
FUNCTION        5        geometry_gist_penalty_2d (internal, internal, internal),
FUNCTION        6        geometry_gist_picksplit_2d (internal, internal),
FUNCTION        7        geometry_gist_same_2d (geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry, internal);
```

This was extracted from this link http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1287#comment:8

Comment: +1 this worked for me. I entered psql, switched to the postgis_template db and then ran this.

Comment: Thanks, I spent many days on this. A really specific problem :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this,if you are using Postgis 2.0 with PostgreSQL 9.1+ there is an easier way:

```
#create your database if necessary and connect to it.
$ createdb  <db name>
$ psql <db name>
```

Then from the psql shell  you run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

From the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#post-installation